# catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS problem

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a package that depends on a message package called stdr_msgs. (stdr_msgs contains only messages). Here is the begining of the corresponding CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(log_and_playback)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp rosbag_storage urdf kdl_parser tf2_ros tf2_kdl
  stdr_msgs stdr_lib blf localize stdr_velodyne ladybug_playback
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rosbag_storage urdf kdl_parser tf2_ros tf2_kdl
    stdr_msgs stdr_lib blf localize stdr_velodyne ladybug_playback
)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
  src/bag_reader.cpp
  [...]
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

Note that find_package searches for stdr_msgs and that the library depends on catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS. This follows the guidelines in http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/cpp_msg_dependencies.html

However, from time to time, the build fails because a header file from one of the messages in stdr_msgs is not found. It fails while compiling one of the cpp files from the library in this package.

Am I missing something?

EDIT: I printed the catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS. It contained the stdr_msgs message generation targets. The list is long, it has 3842 elements from the following packages: actionlib, actionlib_msgs, bond, diagnostic_msgs, driver_base, dynamic_reconfigure, geometry_msgs, nav_msgs, nodelet, pcl_msgs, roscpp, rosgraph_msgs, sensor_msgs, std_msgs, stdr_msgs, tf2_msgs, tf, topic_tools, velodyne_msgs

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205243/catkin_exported_targets-problem/) by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1001 on 2015-03-17

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-03-17**:
Did you print out the contents of `catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS`? Was the target for `stdr_msgs` in there?

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2015-03-17**:
yes, the 3 message generation targets (lisp, py, cpp) for stdr_msgs were there

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-03-17**:
Hmm, not sure, that looks like it should work to me. Are you using `catkin_make`?

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2015-03-18**:
I'm using `catkin_make`. Well, I'll keep digging and eventually report here. Not easy to troubleshoot thought because it does not happen all the time and the testing cycle is long (lots of packages to recompile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

problem was from an upstream package

---

Originally posted by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) with karma: 1001 on 2015-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0